# Alter Oracle table to add datetime column that defaults to current time on new or update to record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The below sql statement is not working, seems to be an issue with the "on" statement. I want to add a new column "LastUpdated" that will automatically populate when a new record is inserted or updated.

```
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD LASTUPDATED DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: I think you need to use a trigger for this functionality.

Comment: I was basing the initial attempt off of the following article by oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: That documentation is for MySQL, not Oracle RDBMS. They are different database products, with different syntax. Oracle doesn't support `on update`, so you'll need to use a trigger.